withNetwork vs withNetworkMode and types of default networks
I am trying to find documentation that clearly explains the difference between
withNetwork and withNetworkMode and when to use which one. Also, what is the use case of Network SHARED defined in org.testcontainers.containers.Network
What all kinds of default networks exist that can be used with withNetworkMode and what is the usecase of each?

TL;DR: you probably don't need .withNetworkMode() at all, and I'd avoid the Network.SHARED singleton.  You probably don't need .withNetwork() either, but if you do, create one with Network.newNetwork().

The Javadocs for org.testcontainers.containers.Container note

withNetwork(Network network): Set the network for this container, similar to the --network <name> option on the docker CLI.
withNetworkMode(java.lang.String networkMode): Set the network mode for this container, similar to the --net <name> option on the docker CLI.

The docker run --net option actually controls two different internal settings.  They're mentioned at least in the very detailed Docker HTTP API documentation.  Of note there, the NetworkMode parameter is documented as

Network mode to use for this container. Supported standard values are: bridge, host, none, and container:<name|id>. Any other value is taken as a custom network's name to which this container should connect to.

These options are also mentioned in the Docker Network Drivers documentation, though not under the name "network mode".  I'd describe the core options here as:

none -- the container has no networking capability at all.  You can't interact with it, even from the host.  You probably don't want this.

host -- Docker's networking system is disabled and the container appears like it's running directly on the host for networking purposes.  It can't communicate with other containers unless they've published ports.  "The host" could be a hidden Linux VM on setups like Docker Desktop, which will make the container unreachable.  You probably don't want this.

container:<id> -- the container shares the network, IP address, and other details with some other container.  This is an unusual setup.  You probably don't want this.

bridge -- the default setting, with Docker networks and the ability to hide or remap published ports.  This is the only setting you want in most cases.


In short, you probably want .withNetworkMode("bridge"), but that's the default option, so you can almost always skip a .withNetworkMode() entirely.
.withNetwork() sets up a Docker network, like you'd create with docker network create, or that a Compose-based setup creates for you.  Testcontainers has a Network object container with a builder pattern for it.  In plain Docker, though, you almost never need to manually set any options on a network, and the Testcontainers documentation example just calls Network.newNetwork() to create it.
Network.SHARED is defined in the source as a network with all default options that can't be explicitly closed.  This doesn't seem to be any different from just creating a Network.newNetwork() yourself, except that it's shared between tests.  This brings along the various lifecycle issues that global singletons bring, and I'd avoid using it.

None of these options matter at all if the containers don't need to communicate with each other.  When I've used Testcontainers, it's to provide a quasi-integration-test environment where I have for example a "real" database that I don't need to mock (and when it's been acceptable to require Docker running for basic tests, I can tolerate the performance impact on my tests, and the DevOps team will allow my application tests to invoke Docker in the CI environment).  I wouldn't try to use Testcontainers to try to replicate my entire application setup; instead, I'd set up a complete Compose file and run an integration test against that, without writing specific Java code to try to set up the containers.
If that's your setup, you don't need any of these network options at all.

Thank you. I am running Java code that needs to talk to say kafka and postgres containers. And also some java code in another container that needs to talk to both kafka and postgres. So I have a mix of all. And also, this is going to run in dind. I have had issues with communication a bit

Kafka itself is written in Java, and there's support to run an in-process Kafka broker; see for example Simple embedded Kafka test example with spring boot.  For a database you can often use an in-process database like H2 or HDBC, or provide mock implementations of your JPA layer.  That can get you around the need to use Testcontainers at all.

NO, my requirement will have many more Java images that I am dockerizing and they need to talk to one another

One more Q. If I create my own network, use service names/alias and also map service ports to host ports, containers can talk to each other and my host service can also then talk to any other docker container as needed or I am missing something?

For this sort of integration test, I'd recommend building the test environment using Docker Compose and not via Testcontainers.  It will be easier to start, stop, manage, and call it (for example using curl).
